# How to get Jndi name in java class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jndi, lookup

I want to get a JNDI value in my java conf Spring.

the context.xml file:

```
<Environment name="foo" type="java.lang.String" value="bar" />
```

the xml spring config:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="foobar" jndi-name="java:comp/env/foo" default-value="nothing"/>
```

the java spring config:

```
@Bean
public String foobar() {
    ???
}
```

If someone could you give me an example it'll be very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Try autowiring `JndiObjectFactoryBean` it will have a [getJndiName()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectLocator.html#getJndiName()) method, which is inherited from  [JndiObjectLocator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectLocator.html)  will expose your jndi name

Try this

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/yourJdbcGoesHere");
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: i don't need a datasource, only a String object. Can i extend my class with org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport ?

Comment: @aMod try Autowiring `JndiObjectFactoryBean`, it will expose your jndi name with `getJndiName()` method